# Spring chaning LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver and InternalResourceViewResolver

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-mobile

I'm having trouble using Spring Mobile 1.1.2 and Spring MVC. The problem I'm having is, that in the application I have all views for desktop and for some desktop, I have mobile alternative.

I use `LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver`, which delegates to `InternalResourceViewResolver`. If both desktop and mobile views are present, everything works fine. On desktop I see desktop version, on mobile I see mobile version. The problem is when the mobile view is not present.

I know, that fallback resolution will only work when delegating to a view resolver which returns null from `resolveViewName(String, Locale)` if it cannot resolve a view. For example, `InternalResourceViewResolver` never returns null, so fallback resolution will not be available. So I didn't hope that will work.

But I tried to chain resolvers, with order 1 `LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver`(delegates to `InternalResourceViewResolver`) and with order 2 `InternalResourceViewResolver` (which point to desktop views all the time regardless on the device). My problem is, that it never gets to resolver number 2. Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Effectivly there is only a single `ViewResolver` only the `LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver` will be consulted. It will create a view name based on the returned view name and by the selected device (or preferences) and use that to retrieve a `View`. The delegating resolver is an `InternalResourceViewResolver` which always resolves to a view because it only constructs a URL.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-mobile/docs/current/reference/html/device.html#d5e351) you just need to enable fullback resolution.

```
<property name="enableFallback" value="true" />
```

hope it helps you !